# AngularJS and Bootstrap ng-repeat table generation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new in angular so maybe my question is trivial, but I have tried to solve this problem for last few days and I gave up.

I need to create a matrix of images (actually they are charts generated by angular-chart module), with 2 columns and dynamically loaded number of images. I want to use Angular's ng-repeat directive. As an result I want to get something like this:

[image](https://s3.postimg.org/y1dbfu7vn/2016_08_23_10_10_07.jpg)

Therefore i have tried to make some code, and after some thoughts I found this resolution:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">{{ item.name }}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{ item.data }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6" ng-init="$index = $index + 1">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">{{ item.name }}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{ item.data }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But unfortunately it seems that it's not possible to modify a value of $index variable of ng-repeat. How to solve this and get dynamically building matrix of images which are based on data stored in an array of objects?

Comment: $index is reserved angular var for ng-repeat. Just rename and use another var.

Comment: Why are you trying to increment `$index`? The `ngRepeat` directive does this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you approach is correct. Try the below code.
In Controller:

```
$scope.items = [{name:'name', data:'Image1'}, 
      {name:'A', data:'Image2'},
      {name:'B', data:'Image3}, 
      {name:'C', data:'Image4'},
      {name:'D', data:'Image4'}, 
      {name:'E', data:'Image5'}];
```

In HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">{{ item.name }}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{ item.data }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('main', []);
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-app="main">  

  
  <div ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]" style="float:left;" >
    <div class="row"  style='padding:10px; '>
        <div class="col-lg-2" style='padding:10px;'>
            <div class="panel panel-primary" style='width:200px' >
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">{{i}}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                   {{i}}
                </div>
            </div>           
        </div>      
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      <!--Please Edit this code is that: -->
      <div class="row">
     <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-include="'content.html'">
     </div>

      <!-- And make file content.html in the same folder have content: -->

    <div class="col-lg-6">
       <div class="panel panel-primary">
           <div class="panel-heading">
             <h3 class="panel-title">{{ item.name }}</h3>
           </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
                {{ item.data }}

     </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve this problem by iterating over different index variable and use it to get proper element, like in the example below.

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [] | range:10 ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">{{ items[i].name }}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    items[i].value
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">{{ items[i+1].name }}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    items[i+1].value
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And a filter in js:

```
myApp.filter('range', function() {
    return function(input, total) {
        total = parseInt(total);

        for (var i=0; i<total; i=i+2) {
          input.push(i);
        }
    return input;
    };
});
```